# How to change my global variable in other function? c#

Tags: c#

I want to change the global integer- amount, by make his value as 'c' value, how can i do that?

```
    public static class Globals
    {
        public const int amount = 5689;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int c = Globals.amount - b;
        textBox3.Text = c.ToString();
        **Globals.amount = c;** // ***how do i set this?***
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since amount is defined as a constant, you can't change it.

You can, however change it if you made it a non-constant static variable instead.

```
public static int amount = 5689;
```